# haxe cannot find csv library installed by haxelib

Tags: ubuntu, classpath, haxe, haxelib

**EDIT:** Leaving this up because other people are bound to have the same issue, but the root cause was that the ubuntu package was a very old version of haxe. I uninstalled that and installed from source instead, and everything just works

---

I have installed haxe globally on my ubuntu system, and set up haxelib as user, with install path /home/mdemello/opt/share/haxe/lib

haxelib appears to work, except for a post-install error:

```
$ haxelib install csv
Downloading csv-0,4,0.zip...
Download complete : 10518 bytes in 4.3s (2.3KB/s)
  Install CHANGES.txt
  Install haxelib.json
  Created lib/
  Install LICENSE.txt
  Install README.md
  Created test/
  Install test.hxml
  Created lib/format/
  Created lib/format/csv/
  Install lib/format/csv/Reader.hx
  Install lib/format/csv/Utf8Reader.hx
  Install lib/format/csv/Data.hx
  Install test/Test.hx
  Current version is now 0.4.0
Done
Invalid field access : index
```

but using the installed library via -lib fails; I have to specify the full path using -cp:

```
$ head CSV.hx
import format.csv.Reader;

$ haxe -lib csv -x CSV.hx
./CSV.hx:1: characters 7-24 : Class not found : format.csv.Reader

$ haxelib path csv
/home/mdemello/opt/share/haxe/lib/csv/0,4,0/
-D csv

$ haxe -cp /home/mdemello/opt/share/haxe/lib/csv/0,4,0/lib/ -x CSV.hx
# works
```

edit: here's the output when running with `haxe -v`:

```
$ haxe -v -lib csv -x CSV.hx
Classpath : /home/mdemello/opt/share/haxe/lib/csv/0,4,0/;./;/usr/share/haxe/std/neko/_std/;/usr/share/haxe/std/
Defines : true;sys;neko;haxe_ver;haxe_release;haxe3;dce;csv
Parsed /usr/share/haxe/std/StdTypes.hx
Parsed /usr/share/haxe/std/neko/_std/String.hx
Parsed /usr/share/haxe/std/neko/_std/Array.hx
Parsed /usr/share/haxe/std/haxe/EnumTools.hx
Parsed /usr/share/haxe/std/neko/_std/Std.hx
Parsed ./CSV.hx
./CSV.hx:1: characters 7-24 : Class not found : format.csv.Reader
```

I note that the classpath it added from -lib was `/home/mdemello/opt/share/haxe/lib/csv/0,4,0/` whereas the one I had to add manually via -cp was `/home/mdemello/opt/share/haxe/lib/csv/0,4,0/lib`

Comment: Does `haxelib list` list the csv lib (which would indicate that it's installed correctly)? Does the `csv` folder in your haxelib directory have a `.current` file with `0.4.0` in it? Edit: also, is that the full error haxelib gives you? No stacktrace?

Comment: yes, `haxelib list` works, and csv has a `.current` file and the `0,4,0` directory. that's also the full error message from haxe. i'll rerun with -v and add the output.

Comment: ah, it seems like a problem with the package itself. symlinking csv/0,4,0/lib/format to csv/lib/format made everything work nicely. i was just unlucky that that was the first haxe package i used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: It looks like the default haxelib on ubuntu (3.0.0) is not honouring the classPath directive in the csv package. The workaround below still works but it shouldn't need to be done. Update haxe instead.

---

looks like an issue with the csv package directory structure. i fixed it by adding the following symlink from `lib/format -> format`:

```
csv
└── 0,4,0
    ├── format -> lib/format/  <--- symlink added
    ├── lib
    │   └── format
    │       └── csv
    └── test
```

Comment: The library uses the `classPath` directive in `haxelib.json` to instruct that the sources are on `/lib`, instead of `/`.  It seams that your setup isn't honoring that instruction for some reason...